# Obtaining point forecasts from a DCC-GARCH model in rmgarch in R

Tags: r, forecasting, multivariate-analysis, garch, volatility-forecasting

I am becoming more acquainted with GARCH models in R, but I am not sure my code is right for what I am trying to do, so I would appreciate any help.

Based on an xts I create using data from a csv with 3 columns of stock data (pictured below),

[image]

I estimate the following basic multivariate GARCH model, with an ARMA(1,0) for the mean:

```
# What each time series is defined by itself
uspec = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1,0)),
                   variance.model = list(garchOrder = c(1,1), model = 'sGARCH'),
                   distribution.model = 'norm')

# Their connected dynamics
mspec = dccspec(uspec = multispec(replicate(3, uspec)),
                dccOrder = c(1,1),
                distribution = "mvnorm")

## Fitting
fit_rm = dccfit(mspec, data = x, solver = c('hybrid','gosolnp'))

## Forecasting
forc_rm = dccforecast(fit_rm, n.ahead = 10)
```

`forc_rm` currently gives me forecasts of the co-variance matrix, which is good, but how do I get forecasts of the 3 time series themselves?

In `rmgarch`'s sister package, `rugarch`, the forecast object contains both conditional volatility forecasts and the actual time series forecasts, but I come up short with `rmgarch`. I only get vague options that do not seem like the return forecasts.

*(pardon large image)*

[image]

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Have your tried my suggestion? Did it solve your problem?

Comment: This is what I get from `fitted(forc_rm)`, https://imgur.com/a/OKvPeDZ
The size of the array and the numbers' magnitude corresponds to a `n.ahead=10` point forecast on my data, which is good, and coincidentally this is the same as what I get from `forc_rm@mforecast$mu`. Is there any way to retrieve the forecasts in some column form, however, because otherwise this format is understandably confusing (a 1D straight array).

Comment: Hmm, it has been a while since I used `rmgarch` for forecasting a DCC-GARCH model. I vaguely remember it as a multidimensional array, not one-dimensional, but perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: It turns out that my chosen R work environment of Jupyter is a bit buggy, and was portraying the correlation/covariance matrices as arrays, but this does not occur in RStudio. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `fitted(forc_rm)`? The [help file](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rmgarch/versions/1.3-0/topics/DCCforecast-class) suggests this is the conditional mean forecast:

> The conditional mean forecast array of dimensions `n.ahead` x `n.assets` by `(n.roll+1)`. The thirds dimension of the array has the `T+0` index label.

Alternatively, adding a DCC structure on top of univariate ARMA-GARCH models does not change the point forecasts of the series involved. Hence, you can obtain them by applying the function `ugarchforecast` on the univariate specification objects `uspec` and the data. That is, `forecast <- ugarchforecast(uspec, data=x, ...)`